# adding jquery a href class selector after PHP entry has been called to DOM dynamically

Tags: php, jquery, dynamic, jquery-selectors

I've been trying to come up with a solution for this problem. I thought .live() would help but it isn't used in jquery 1.9.1

I have this function - the gist of which is this:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $currentID = $row['UserID'];
    $query2="SELECT FirstName, LastName, UserID FROM Users WHERE UserID = $currentID";
    $result2 = $mysqli->query($query2);
    $row1 = $result2->fetch_assoc();
    echo '<div class="commentEntry">';
    echo "<h5><a href='user.php?User=".$row1['UserID']."'>".$row1['FirstName']." ".$row1['LastName']."</a></h5>";
    echo "<p>".$row['Content']."</p>";
    echo "<p class='agree'><a href='#' class='agreeWith' id=".$row['commentID'].">Agree</a></p>";
    echo "</div>";
}
```

This function works, it isn't the issue.
So essentially with jquery I want to get hold of all dynamically added instances of a.agreeWith.

To test, I am using this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('a.agreeWith').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("test");
        var agree = $(this).id;
        var data = 'Agree='  + agree.val();
    });
});
```

Now what I find isn't happening, is that the alert never appears. The a href link still triggers and so clearly there is no call.

I have tested it simply by writing whatever into the page, and it works, the alert appears.

So clearly there is an issue with dynamically loaded information and trying to apply jquery to it.

The question is. How do I get around this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: see http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: I tried it with:
$('a.agreeWith').on('click', function(event) {
But encountered the same issue

Comment: Are you able to execute the "$('a.agreeWith').click( ... )" (or variation) in your JavaScript console and have it work as expected?

Comment: I can do, it works as expected with this implementation in console:
$('a.agreeWith').on("click", function(event) {              
  event.preventDefault();
  alert("test"); });

Comment: Within your "$(document).ready(function(event) {", add a console.log of "$('a.agreeWith')" and see what a reload outputs to the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you  at least to get your alert working.  Not sure what your trying to do after....

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $(document.body).on('click', 'a.agreeWith', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("test");
        var agree = $(this).id;
        var data = 'Agree='  + agree.val();
    });
});
```

Comment: That worked :) Thank you. I didn't think to call document.body

Comment: Ya, its a very broad way to specify.  You can use document body to test that it works and then work down the DOM tree from there to be more efficient if you need to.